# Include PHP in all files

Tags: php, configuration, include, config, require

I've made a `config.php` file which contains all definitions and variables that should be used in all over my website, and I should include it in every single page (paying attention at different relative paths)...

Is there a way to make this file automatically visible from all *PHP* files without manually including it every time?

Or is there an alternative way to make all *constant* definitions visible everywhere?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using composer?

Comment: I'm using no frameworks

Comment: Composer its used only in Frameworks you can use it as Class Loader. Take a look at this example: https://getcomposer.org/apidoc/master/Composer/Autoload/ClassLoader.html

Comment: @LuísAssunção I can't understant it completely... Is it an auto-includer?

Comment: yes. I meant is not only used by frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

A way is to build your web PHP app with an unique enter point, instead of several points (different PHP files). This unique point will be the main index.php, wich will load config.php and also the PHP file according for the requested URL. So, in your operating PHP files you don't need to include config, because they're included by index.php instead. This is a strategy matter. Obviously, you need to think well before start to build. Or you can rely on an existing framework or something.

Comment: Do you mean that I should use an empty *index.php* file which redirects to the desired file according to the data sent to him?

Comment: Not empty at all: it will include config.php, open page (header), include (not redirect) file according to the data sent, and close page (footer).

Comment: It could help! What about URLs? Should I apply URL rewrite to every page?

Comment: You can determine the section or page you want to load by passing a variable by GET, but of course it would be nice if you use friendly URLs rewriting for example yourdomain.com/my-section/ to yourdomain.com/index.php?page=my-section

Comment: Here you are a very very simple approach (with no URL rewriting, but it would be easy to add it to .htaccess) https://programadorphpfreelance.com/repositorio/sample.zip However, you are building from zero, it is funny and you will learn a lot, but please consider start from a framework or something.

Comment: I'll consider a framework too in the future but it is my first website and I prefer starting from zero :)

Comment: Could you link me a good tutorial for URL rewriting, just because most of them are really different and it is a bit confusing...

Comment: Sure, rewriting is confusing, learn picking from different sources, searching for concrete things you wanna do. I added basic URL rewriting to .htaccess in sample.zip posted before, download and take a loook.